Apache Spark On EKS master, failed to connect S3 using IAM role
We are running our Spark application on EKS as master. And trying to access(read/write) files in S3 bucket using IAM role.
We have configured SA and attached IAM role to that Service account using annotations.
We are able to connect S3 bucket using IAM role when master is set to local[*] (local mode) from EKS.
When we run our application on EKS using  master as -k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443, then we are getting access denied to connect S3 using the same IAM role.
Please note that S3 connection working fine if we use credentials(access/secret keys)
Below configs set:
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
//other spark configs
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain")
    .getOrCreate();
    spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com");
    spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.region", awsRegion);
    spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true");
    spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
    spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A");

